# How to use different GPUs to render and for the UI?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I have read somewhere on the blender site that when rendering with Gpu, you may get limited ui control or something, so if you want to have control and render at the same time you have to use 2 graphics cards, one for rendering and one for ui.

My specs: 
b450m ds3h, 
Ryzen 5 2400g with integrated graphics, 
Rx 580 8gb

So, would it be possible that i would plug my monitor in the Motherboard, but set the render device in the settings to my rx 580, so i'd render with rx 580 but use the integrated graphics for ui and other tasks in the background (YT, gimp...)?

And yes i know that i would have to switch the hdmi cable to my gpu when gaming.

I know it works that way with 2 dedicated gpus, but i dont know about integrated, so i asked you. Thanks a lot!